# CSS grid: How to make 3 items per row but for case with 5 items next 2 should go in center

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a case where now I have 5 items on the list.
On the layout it should go as 3 items first row and 2 items second row but in the center;
My CSS code is not working for cases with 5 elements since the second row starts from the left.

```
.items{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(340px, 1fr));
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 32px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 24px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
}
```